# Swagger error when trying to export from AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When I call the exporter url :
https:///restapis//stages//exports/swagger
as per documented in
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html

I get this error:

Unable to build exporter: Error creating bean with name 'swaggerExporter' defined in class path resource [com/amazonaws/backplane/controlservice/configuration/ImportExportConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.amazonaws.backplane.controlservice.importexport.Exporter com.amazonaws.backplane.controlservice.configuration.ImportExportConfig.swaggerExporter(java.util.Map,java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is because some of the headers in the request were not present.

You should have

- accept header
- host header

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html#api-gateway-export-api-download-swagger-json